# Type stable functions in Julia for general distribution when working with floating point inputs

Tags: types, floating-point, julia, type-stability

In Julia, I have a function like this:

```
function f(x::Float64, c::Float64)
    if x <= 0
        return(0.0)
    elseif x <= c
        return(x / c)
    else
        return(1.0)
    end
end
```

The function is type-stable and so will run quickly. However, I want to include the function in a package for general distribution, including to 32-bit machines. What is best practice here? Should I write another version of the function for `Float32` (this could get annoying if I have many such functions)? Could I use `FloatingPoint` for the input types instead? If I do this, how do I ensure the function remains type-stable, since `0.0` and `1.0` are `Float64`, while `x / c` could potentially be `Float32` or `Float16`? Maybe I could use type parameters, e.g. `T<:FloatingPoint` and then let `x::T` and `c::T`, and then use `0.0::T` and `1.0::T` in the body of the function to ensure it is type-stable?

Any guidance here would be appreciated.

Comment: 32 bit machines do support `Float64` fine. The 32/64 bit distinction applies only to integers.

Comment: @MrAlpha Thanks, that is useful information,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `one` and `zero` functions are useful here:

```
function f(x, c)
    if x <= 0
        return zero(x)
    elseif x <= c
        return x/c
    else
        return one(x)
    end
end
```

This version is a bit more strict about the input types:

```
function f{T<:FloatingPoint}(x::T, c::T)
    if x <= 0
        return zero(T)
    elseif x <= c
        return x/c
    else
        return one(T)
    end
end
```